# How to enable blued Core Bluetooth XPC logging in OSX 10.9.2

Tags: macos, core-bluetooth, iobluetooth

Is there any way to re-enable logging of blued Core Bluetooth XPC messages?

In OSX 10.9.1, the system log contains messages that look like the listing below when I am using IOBluetooth to speak to a Bluetooth LE device. However, in OSX 10.9.2 (2014-02-25), the system log does not contain these messages anymore when I am using IOBluetooth. Is there any way to re-enable blued RPC logging, so I can at least get a little more information when trying to [diagnose bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028998/does-blued-cache-att-values-and-how-to-clear-the-cache)?

```
2/26/14 10:07:02.544 AM blued[3838]: Incoming Core Bluetooth message 1: <dictionary: 0x7fbf93c0fc90> { count = 3, contents =
    "kCBMsgArgType" => <int64: 0x7fbf93c1a0e0>: 0
    "kCBMsgArgOptions" => <dictionary: 0x7fbf93c1a970> { count = 1, contents =
        "kCBInitOptionShowPowerAlert" => <int64: 0x7fbf93c1f1f0>: 1
    }
    "kCBMsgArgName" => <string: 0x7fbf93c0f400> { length = 13, contents = "MyApp" }
}
2/26/14 10:07:02.547 AM blued[3838]: Incoming Core Bluetooth message 29: <dictionary: 0x7fbf95b04280> { count = 2, contents =
    "kCBMsgArgUUIDs" => <array: 0x7fbf95b00160> { count = 0, capacity = 0, contents =
    }
    "kCBMsgArgOptions" => <dictionary: 0x7fbf95b04710> { count = 0, contents =
    }
}
2/26/14 10:07:11.102 AM blued[3838]: Incoming Core Bluetooth message 30
2/26/14 10:07:11.106 AM blued[3838]: Incoming Core Bluetooth message 31: <dictionary: 0x7fbf93e12ea0> { count = 2, contents =
    "kCBMsgArgOptions" => <dictionary: 0x7fbf93e13240> { count = 0, contents =
    }
    "kCBMsgArgDeviceUUID" => <uuid: 0x7fbf93e040a0> F74FF592-4628-4D69-BBAA-CF548E38513D
}
2/26/14 10:07:11.378 AM blued[3838]: Incoming Core Bluetooth message 44: <dictionary: 0x7fbf93e07fc0> { count = 2, contents =
    "kCBMsgArgUUIDs" => <array: 0x7fbf93e12620> { count = 0, capacity = 0, contents =
    }
    "kCBMsgArgDeviceUUID" => <uuid: 0x7fbf93e02840> F74FF592-4628-4D69-BBAA-CF548E38513D
}
2/26/14 10:07:11.379 AM blued[3838]: Incoming Core Bluetooth message 61: <dictionary: 0x7fbf95800940> { count = 4, contents =
    "kCBMsgArgUUIDs" => <array: 0x7fbf95802200> { count = 0, capacity = 0, contents =
    }
    "kCBMsgArgServiceStartHandle" => <int64: 0x7fbf95802b20>: 1
    "kCBMsgArgServiceEndHandle" => <int64: 0x7fbf958004b0>: 4
    "kCBMsgArgDeviceUUID" => <uuid: 0x7fbf95800a60> F74FF592-4628-4D69-BBAA-CF548E38513D
}
```

Comment: This would be great for iOS too. Can you open a bug with Apple until someone answers this question? It would be great to have their input.